# InfluxDb: How can I combine two measurements which do not match on timestamp into a new time series?

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

We are introducing InfluxDb into our organization, and have met our first hurdle: combining two timeseries into one.

Every 24 hours, we collect the firmware data from a large number of devices. They end up in a measurement more or less like this:

```
time                 deviceId                               value
----                 -------                               -----
1506808800000000000  ad0277c6-3513-4769-80f2-819516856e18  2017.10.1
1506808800000000000  db7c5414-ae9e-4303-bafe-b0d70a46d01b  2017.10.1
1506895200000000000  ad0277c6-3513-4769-80f2-819516856e18  2017.10.2
1506895200000000000  db7c5414-ae9e-4303-bafe-b0d70a46d01b  2017.10.2
1506981600000000000  ad0277c6-3513-4769-80f2-819516856e18  2017.10.3
1507327200000000000  ad0277c6-3513-4769-80f2-819516856e18  2017.10.7
1507586400000000000  ad0277c6-3513-4769-80f2-819516856e18  2017.10.10
1507704360000000000  db7c5414-ae9e-4303-bafe-b0d70a46d01b  2017.10.10
1507704360000000000  ad0277c6-3513-4769-80f2-819516856e18  2017.10.11
1507704360000000000  ad0277c6-3513-4769-80f2-819516856e18  2017.10.10
```

The devices in question also generate certain values, and we keep track of how the quality of these in a "missingValues" timeseries (where value is the number of missing values, and batchSize is the number of expected values - a value of 24 indicates 100% loss, 0 is no loss):

```
----                ---------   -------                              -----
time                batchSize   deviceId                             value
1507413600000000000 24          ad0277c6-3513-4769-80f2-819516856e18 0
1507413600000000000 24          ad0277c6-3513-4769-80f2-819516856e18 3
1507413600000000000 24          ad0277c6-3513-4769-80f2-819516856e18 7
1507413600000000000 24          db7c5414-ae9e-4303-bafe-b0d70a46d01b 2
```

As stated, the firmware timeseries is updated once every 24 hours, while the missingValues timeseries is updated intermittently. When a missingValues value is entered, I need to get the latest firmware version for that particular device id and combine it with the rest of the missing values tags and fields to form "missing_values_with_firmware". The goal is to be able to do (pseudocode) "select deviceId, avg(value/batchSize) from missing_values_with_firmware" to analyze the impace of the firmware on the data quality.

What would be the best approach to do this? I have tried creating a continuous query, but I'm having trouble getting my head around how to do the sub select part of
select time, value, batchsize, deviceId, (select last(value) from firmware where deviceId = m.deviceId and time <= m.time)

Would kapacitor be a better alternative?